# including different headers for i386 and x86_64 when compiling universal libraries for mac via cmake

Tags: macos, openssl, cmake

I am building an universal library on mac. My library uses `openssl` functions and links against `openssl` libraries. I can get the `openssl` code compiled for i386 and x86_64 separately and then create a fat library to make it a universal library for i386 and x86_64.

My library is compiled via `cmake` by setting `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=i386;x86_64` to make it universal between i386 and x86_64
The `openssl` headers generated for i386 and x86_64 are different. How do I make `cmake` select different headers for i386 and x86_64?

Comment: That's an interesting observation about the headers. Could you edit your question and add an example of the differences between an i386 header and a x96_64 header? I ask because I build fat libraries for iOS, and they include ARM and i386 (i386 for emulator debugging).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the current openssl build process does not support OS X universal builds directly.  One way to do it is to just compile each architecture separately and then afterwards combine the two variants of each library file into a combined universal file by using `lipo -combine`.  See `man 1 lipo`.  There is an example here:  https://gist.github.com/tmiz/1441111

Comment: Yes i can combine the two openssl libraries into one fat library, but the openssl headers are different between i386 and x86_64 architectures. How can i create a unified headers ?

Comment: I don't know if anyone has tried to do that. Have you found any architecture-specific values in the headers that are not covered by preprocessor conditionals? Apple's port of openssl for OS X 10.6 is here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL096/OpenSSL096-15/ and the current MacPorts portfile is here: https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/openssl/Portfile.  Both support universal builds but, with a quick glance, I don't see any attempts to patch the header files.

Answer (score 0):

> including different headers for i386 and x86_64 when compiling universal libraries for mac ...

I don't believe you can do it for a universal or fat library.

In this case, where you want different headers for architectures, you might need to leap to a framework because a framework allows multiple sets of headers. But I don't think I have seen it used for architecture independence.

The [Introduction to Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html) discusses the on disk layout of the bundle under [Anatomy of Framework Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html), *Additional Directories*:

```
Directory     | Description
--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Headers       | Contains any public headers you want to make available to external developers.
--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Documentation | Contains HTML or PDF files describing the framework interfaces. Typically, 
              | documentation directories do not reside at the top level of your framework.
              | Instead, they reside inside your language-specific resource directories.
--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries     | Contains any secondary dynamic libraries your framework requires.
```